# ICU add custom character set detection

Tags: c++, internationalization, icu

Does somebody know how ICU Charset Detector's data is built. And is it difficult to add additional languages?

For example, I saw in the bug tracker that a ticket for the detection of Thai is opened since 2007 but nothing new until today.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would ask your question on the ICU mailing list or even [file a bug](http://icu-project.org) and say you are willing to put in the work/data to do it. I couldn't find the ticket you referred to, but ICU is open source, so if you are willing to contribute time and data, that would make a difference in implementation.